# PHP Gmail API Get Attachments Returns Request Object

Tags: php, gmail, guzzle

thanks for any help anyone can offer, having issues with the Gmail API for PHP. Currently, I am attempting to get the data of a PDF attachment for an email using:

```
Google_Service_Gmail->users_messages_attachments->get('me', $messageId, $attachmentId);
```

It seems that this is supposed to return a response object, from which one can use ->getData() to get the information needed. However, in this case it keeps returning a Guzzle Request Object. Wondering if anyone else has ran into this?

Comment: That does not look like valid PHP code. Its also useful to have a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When you say it doesn't look like valid PHP code, to which part are you referring?

Comment: This looks a bit PHP `Google_Service_Gmail->` but I would expect a `$` at the start

Comment: Ah yea, in code I have that as a variable that's instantiated way above, just have that bit there for improved clarity for the post.

Comment: Please remember, we can only see what you show us!!! We will point out what does not make sense unless you make the code you show us make sense

Comment: Ok it sounds like I need to clarify what I've written. This line of code takes a Google_Service_Gmail object and then does the users_messages_attachments->get method on it. This method is supposed to return a response object. However, it has been returning a request object for me. My question is why is it returning a request object when it should be returning a response object.